# Making a phone call to Lead from Agents mobile phone

Tags: servicecloud, call-center

I want to have a button on Lead record which will allow user(Sales Agent) to make a call to Lead(Customer) from Agent's mobile phone.
With CTI configuration, we can make a call from Desktop but the requirement is the call has to go from Agent's mobile phone.

Any suggestion/thought is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented custom page or component, then you can use `a` tag with phone number which will open in dial pad

This is a phone link:

```
<a href="tel:+4733378901">+47 333 78 901</a>
```